# Strip full screen in fixed twitter bootstrap layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, liquid-layout

I would like to create this layout with twitter bootstrap.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6mn7.png

This my start Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/antoc/n8ec9j2h/

My html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3 class="bg-blue">title</h3>

            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
                <h3 class="bg-red">title</h3>

            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
             <h3 class="bg-green">title</h3>

            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problems are:

1. how to create the blu, red and green strip in css?
2. how to create the yellow background in css?

Comment: You have to put effort in your question. Go do some research and we will be happy to answer your question. http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: I looked at my similar problems without finding a similar case

Comment: sorry dowomenfart, this is my first post, I've added some html and link to jsfiddle. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some margin/padding hackery into it... like [**this updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/n8ec9j2h/24/embedded/result/)

Here's the relevent CSS:

```
.bg-yellow{
    background:yellow;
    margin:-10px 0 -9999px -9999px;
    padding:10px 0 9999px 9999px;
}
.bg-blue {
    margin-left:-1000px;
    padding-left:1000px;
}

.bg-green, .bg-red{
    margin-right:-1000px;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3 class="bg-blue">title</h3>
            <div class="bg-yellow">
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h3 class="bg-red">title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <h3 class="bg-green">title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than some padding editing for the yellow box and some text content, I think this is what you wanted:
http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/n8ec9j2h/17/

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 bg-yellow">
                    <h3 class="bg-blue">title</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                    <h3 class="bg-red">title</h3>

                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>

                <h3 class="bg-green">title</h3>

                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Take a closer look at the pic the OP provided. They're looking for just the color to extend, not the whole row (no need for the container-fluid class)